# Android Open WebView In Background Service And Capture Screen Shot

Tags: android, service, background, webview, hidden

I'm trying to open URL in a WebView from a background service then take a screenshot of the hidden WebView.

Funnily enough it is not working! Is this possible? Some code snippets:

```
webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
...
final Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
final Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
picture.draw(c);
....
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible due security

Comment: please take a look to that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745988/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-pa

Comment: Stefan - thanks I have code to save the webview, the problem is doing it hidden in a background service.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo - which bit in particular is not possible due to security? Is there an alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See my question [Android: take a 'screenshot' of a web page from a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049448/android-take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page-from-a-background-service)

You have to get your bitmap from the webview's drawing cache eg.

```
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = mWebView.getDrawingCache();
```

You also have to set the "size" of the WebView, so that it is not 0 x 0 size.