# Capture Android Screen Cordova PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, capture

I was trying to implement this feature in Apache Cordova PhoneGap, but it doesn't work for me

[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

[How can I programmatically take a screenshot of a webview, capturing the full page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745988/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-pa)

When I call to

```
 WebView browserView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);
```

I am actually getting a reference to the following object

```
 LinearLayoutSoftKeyboardDetect
```

and not to the WebView.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova/PhoneGap-based Applications encapsulate the WebView into a DroidGap class that ultimately extends from CordovaActivity [CordovaActivity](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java). This Activity holds a protected component called containing the wiew **CordovaWebView appView** and configured with an **ID equals to 100**:

```
protected CordovaWebView appView;
...
this.appView.setId(100);
```

Thus, you should be able to find the View by seeking the ID 100 doing something like this:

```
CordovaWebView view = (CordovaWebView) activity.findViewById(100);
Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap (picture.getWidth(), 
                                picture.getHeight(), 
                                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
picture.draw(new Canvas(b));
FileOutputStream foss = new FileOutputStream(out);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, foss);
foss.close();
```

This should work.