# Android - unable to get full page WebView Screenshot

Tags: android, webview

I got a function takes screenshot only visible screen, not taking full WebView screenshot.

It does not give hidden or scrolled content, just take snap of current view.

Here is my code.

```
public File getBitmapFromwebchartView(WebView view2) {

    if (view2 != null) {
        view2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = view2.getDrawingCache();
        if (b != null) {

            try {

                //File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Screenshot" + ".jpg");
                fi   = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Realitycheck" + ".jpg");

                // write the bytes in file
                FileOutputStream fo;

                fo = new FileOutputStream(fi);

                b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return fi;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745988/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-pa

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26353881/1777090

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
 Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

                    picture.draw( c );
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {

                        fos = new FileOutputStream( "mnt/sdcard/screenshot.jpg" );
                            if ( fos != null )
                            {
                                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                                fos.close();
                            }
                        }
                   catch(Exception e) {}
```