# Screenshot iOS: WebView Context : Full page screenshot and not just visible viewport

Tags: ios, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I need to take screenshot of Safari browser on iOS, but the screenshot has to be of whole page rather than just visible viewport. Like we get in firefox in WebDriver. Any suggestions?

Currently Using: Selenium and Appium

PS: I prefer not using any external applications, maybe any solutions via selenium/appium.

Answer (score 0):

Install any of the below app.

Barry:-http://barryapp.com/

Website Screenshot :- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/website-screenshot/id437683442?mt=8#

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links pooja, but im avoiding using any external applications. Is there a way it can be done via selenium/appium code.