# How I can to take screenshot of html page with video in webview on api 24?

Tags: android, video, webview, screenshot, android-pixel-copy

I need to take a screenshot on Android API 24.

If I'm using something like the code below, I'm able to take the screenshot but a video on the html page is black square!

```
  float scale = webView.getScale();
  int height = (int) (webView.getContentHeight() * scale + 0.5);
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  webView.draw(canvas);
```

I try to use PixelCopy but I can do it in Android Nuget!

How can I make a screenshot of the html page with webview videos on api 24?

Comment: check below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745988/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-pa

Comment: Is the video encrypted - if so this is the expected behaviour?